# PTIJ: Are there any situations historically, where people are named after names of Tefillot?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I know some people who were named after various tefillot:

- Asher Yatzar
- Annie Zemiros
- Roz Sodecha
- Billy Reishis
- Billy Tachlis
- Moe Dim
- Al Coulomb (He's an electrician)

Does the Talmud or any other Rabbinical writings mention anyone else who has named their children after tefillot?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Billy Nader? 15

Comment: @danf. I REALLY do know someone named "Yeshiva" (I'm serious). The non-Jewish family had no idea what the word ment. They j"ust liked the sound of it".  Given that, I suppose it is very possible that someone would name a child after a prayer. Something strikes me odd about my last sentence.

Comment: Perhaps consider marking an answer correct if you like it...

Comment: Eli Tzion (...)

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi [Baruch Mordechai](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%99) Ezrachi

Comment: Does he have a cousin named Arur Haman ?

Answer (score 2):

My father, Oliver Shalom
................................

Comment: That's not really a tefillah...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about *people*, but several of God's many names and monikers come from the names of prayers. He is called...

- *Ribono shel olam* after a prayer said during *birkas kohanim* on *yom tov*;
- *Kah Keli* after a poem said before *musaf* on the three *r'galim*;
- *Kel erech apayim* after a short supplication said before the Torah reading on weekdays;
- *Adon olam* after a poem recited each morning;
- *Hashem Hashem* after a prayer recited before *tachanun*; and
- *Harachaman* after various short prayers recited after *birkas hamazon*.

Answer (score 1):

I actually once heard about someone who named their kid Hashem.

- David Mizmor
- Al Tzion
- Baruch Atta (he's Sephardi)
- Benzi Aron
- Asher Riyoshvei
- Billy Nader (Ralph's brother)
- Uwe Lezion
- Midas Deen
- Shulem Ruv
- Raz de Sabá
- Al Hasdikem

Comment: I'm not sure if Billy Nader or Al Tzion are names of Tefillot. I understand that Hashem is a somewhat common Arabic name. King Jordan was / is from the "Hashemite" dynasty, no? I wouldn't be surprised if there's an etymological relationship.

Comment: @DanF, misread the question as names from tefillot :)

Comment: I see you had a bissel too much to drink too early. Reserve the schnapps for 2 weeks.

Comment: @DanF, nothing to drink, except for simchat Adar

Comment: i actually know a boy named Rav Ashi

Comment: @DanF, the Arabic name is actually Hashim. I doubt that there is an etymological relationship, as Arabic does not use a prefix like Hebrew. Assuming that "shim" is the Arabic for שם, the Arabic way of saying Hashem would be Ash Shim.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Can't get Purim out of your mind, huh? That's good; Sefira can be a bit "depressing". Thanks for the interesting etymology. Arabic & Hebrew have many similarities (makes sense).

Comment: @DanF, actually, I was searching for another question, which I couldn't find, although I enjoy reading PTIJ throughout the year.

Answer (score 1):

Shimon A. Esrei

Simona Esrei (Shimon's wife).

Pesach Sedder